# Defining a property method in Django with a ForeignKey

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I'm working with my Django app, in which I have two models: `Store` and `Turn`. There is a one-to-many relationship where a store has many turns that need to be processed. This is the code:

```
class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    adress = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=)

    @property
    def average_wait_time(self):
        return #here's the problem

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Turn(models.Model):
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    creation_time = models.TimeField(auto_now=True)
    completion_time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def complete(self):
        self.completion_time = timezone.now()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Turno a las {creation_time} para el Negocio {completion_time}'
```

As you can see, I have a `@property` method that I need to use in order to calculate the average wait time in a store, determined by the average of the turn durations. How can I make this work? I cannot access the `Turn` model from the 'Store' model...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `related_name`

What you need is the `related_name` argument in `ForeignKey`. It works as follows:

```
store = models.ForeignKey(Store, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="turns")
```

This means you can now access all of the turns of a particular store as follows:

```
store = Store.objects.get(id=1)  # get a store
turns = store.turns
```

`turns` in the above will be a queryset of `Turn` objects.

Note also, that if you don't specify a `related_name` django actually creates one for you automatically by adding `_set` onto the end of the related model name in lowercase, and you can do the same with the following:

```
turns = store.turn_set
```

But it's probably better to name the `related_name` explicitly.

#### Your particular case

```
class Store(models.Model):
    ...

    @property
    def average_wait_time(self):
        turns = self.turns
        total_time = sum([turn.completion_time - turn.creation_time for turn in turns.all()])
        average_time = total_time / turns.count()
        return average_time
```

You can also do this using `aggregate` and `Avg`, but the above is probably fine.